# Many to many relationship with itself and combine results

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I've got the next database relation

This table defines the id of an entity

```
   ID
    1
    2
    3
    4
```

And this the relation into this table and it self

```
ID_A  ID_B
 1      2
 2      1  
 3      1
```

I've got this mapping in my entity and it works properly

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "AGRUPACION_MOTIVOS_INDEBIDO", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_MOTIVO_INDEBIDO_A", referencedColumnName = "ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_MOTIVO_INDEBIDO_B", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
private List<MotivoIndebido> motivosA = new ArrayList<>();

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "AGRUPACION_MOTIVOS_INDEBIDO", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_MOTIVO_INDEBIDO_B", referencedColumnName = "ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_MOTIVO_INDEBIDO_A", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
private List<MotivoIndebido> motivosB = new ArrayList<>();
```

But i need to combine this two list in one with all results with no duplicate cases. I mean:

The result list should contain something like:

```
ID_A  IB_B
 1      2
 1      3
```

Can i accomplish this with hibernate or jpa or i need to combine this list manually in a java method?.
And then i should save and delete data manually too?

Sorry for my english and thanks in advice.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your example. How do you get that result list from the relation you've described above? Why shouldn't the values in ID_A not be used? Where does that value 3 for ID_B come from? Besides that, would it suffice to just build a set from both the lists after having loaded the data (which would happen anyway due to the EAGER fetch type)?

Comment: The relation is bidirectional so if you have an relation 1-3 and 2-1 if you show the result of 1 it should be 1-2 1-3... and the values can be repeated in the database but you shouldn't show it so if u have 1-2 and 2-1 only 1-2 should be show

Comment: I'm still not quite sure I get it :) - If the relation is bidirectional and basically the same then why do you have 2 lists in the first place?

Comment: Because how can u create a bidirectional relationship in the same entity without two list? I mean how can you have the A-B and the B-A relation with the same entity without having two list and two mappings.https://blog.jbaysolutions.com/2013/06/06/jpa-2-tutorial-many-to-many-with-self-2/

Comment: Well, you'll need that mapping table anyway so you could as well create an entity that holds references to one entity each (i.e. you map the relation itself). Alternatively you _can_ use 2 collections (I'd probably use sets instead of lists) but only one should be the owner of that relation, otherwise you could get inconsistencies. The other collection would just be a "mappedBy" relation (you find that in the blog post you've linked).

Comment: If I do this one list contains the relations between A->B and the other B->A but i need to combine both. I mean if your have a relation between 1-2 and 3-1 the a list will result 1 result and the other 1 result and i need one list with all the ocurrences of the 1 , i mean one list with 2 and 3 because both have a relation with 1!